# Change font for units with \unit (In LyX, \unittwo)

Tags: beamer, fonts, lyx, units

Using the command (defined in units.sty) `\unit[value]{dimensions}`, the dimensions are set using `\mathrm`.
I am working on a presentation that uses the standard Beamer sans serif font (can't remember name), which means that whenever I use the `\unit` command, the dimensions stand out because of a different font.
Is there a way to redefine what font to use for the dimensions?

By the way, I am using LyX, so the `\unit` command is invoked by calling `\unittwo` and then inserting value in first box and dimensions in second box. I can't seem to find a way to change the font, except by avoiding the `\unit` commands altogether.

I was looking for something like (in the preamble) `\newcommand{\unit}{\sffamily\unit}` but that doesn't work. (I am very inexperienced with using `newcommand`)

Comment: Where is `\unit` defined? Or what package are you loading that provides `\unit`?

Comment: I believe it is defined in units.sty, see http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/units

Comment: The SI standard says "Print unit symbols in roman (upright) type regardless of the type style used in the surrounding text." LaTeX is trying to help you do the right thing...you should let it.

Comment: It seems weird to me. I agree that the units should always be upright, and apparently a half space next to the value. But can it really be the case that the SI system has defined which font to use for units? So that if surrounding text is sans serif, then the units will ALWAYS be WITH serif anyway?

Comment: According to the manual, the units are typeset in the font of the surrounding text when in text mode, but in roman font when in math mode, so I guess you're writing the units as part of a math expression. If so, a tedious workaround is to place all the units in a `\text{}` (requires `amsmath`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [`units` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/units) comments (in [`units.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/units/units.dtx), lines 328-329):

```
%    The use of upright fonts for the dimension is forced in math
%    mode.  Units in text mode are typeset with the currently active font.
```

Here's a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) that highlights this output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}% http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer
\usepackage{units}% http://ctan.org/pkg/units
\begin{document}
some text \unit[17]{mm} some more text

some text $\unit[17]{mm}$ some more text
\end{document}
```

To avoid this, you have a number of choices:

1. Redefine the way `\unit` works to insert `\mathsf` instead of `\mathrm`. You can copy the definition from the source and update it accordingly. Here's an update that just fixes the use of `\mathrm`:

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \DeclareRobustCommand*{\unit}[2][]{%
     \begingroup
       \def\0{#1}%
       \expandafter
     \endgroup
     \ifx\0\@empty
     \else
       #1%
       \ifthenelse{\boolean{B@UnitsLoose}}{~}{\,}%
     \fi
     \ifthenelse{\boolean{mmode}}{\mathsf{#2}}{#2}% <---- Fixed
   }
   \makeatletter
   ```

   Place the above in your document preamble (Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble). For an explanation of why the macro is wrapped within a `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` pair, see [What do `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/5764)
2. Use [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)'s cousin [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch) to patch `\unit` in a similar way to the above suggestion:

   ```
   \usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch
   % \xpatchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
   \xpatchcmd{\unit}{\mathrm}{\mathsf}{}{}
   ```
3. Make a global change in your document, letting *all* `\mathrm` be equivalent to `\mathsf`:

   ```
   \let\mathrm\mathsf% \mathrm is equivalent to \mathsf
   ```

In all of the above instances, the MWE now outputs:

[image]

Nowadays it is advised to use the [`siunitx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) instead, since it allows for more control over unit formatting (globally and locally).

Comment: Perfect! Great explanation and examples.I went with solution 2. which worked right away.

Comment: Great! I also applied solution 2 to `\unitfrac`: `\xpatchcmd{\unitfrac}{\mathrm}{\mathsf}{}{}`. In my use case I transfered an article to `beamer` and therefore I needed sans serif math fonts.